# How to compare two SQLite databases on Linux

Tags: sql, linux, sqlite

Using Linux, I want to compare two SQLite databases that have the same schema.
There will be just a few differences.

Is there a tool that would output these differences?
Preferably output them to the command line, so that I can grep/sed them.

SQLite uses SQL, so a general SQL tool might also do.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Please have a look at the [SQLite Release 3.8.10](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_8_10.html) which was released on May 7, 2015. This release for the first time contains the [*sqldiff.exe* utility program](https://www.sqlite.org/sqldiff.html) for computing the differences between two SQLite database files. Most likely this program will also be part of future releases.

The *sqldiff.exe* command-line line tool should work for all supported operating systems and offers several switches for altering its output behavior. Example usage:

```
sqldiff [options] database1.sqlite database2.sqlite
```

If no options are specified, then the output of *sqldiff.exe* is SQL statements that will transform `database1.sqlite` (the "source" database) into `database2.sqlite` (the "destination" database).

However, there are also certain limitations. For example, the *sqldiff.exe* utility (at least currently) does not display differences in TRIGGERs, VIEWs, or virtual tables.

---

**Sample command and output**

I took a simple key-value store database (`db1.sqlite`) and made
a copy of it (`db2.sqlite`). I then inserted one key-value pair into
`db2.sqlite`. After that I ran the following command:

```
sqldiff db1.sqlite db2.sqlite
```

and got the following output:

> INSERT INTO my_table(rowid,"key",value) VALUES(1,'D:\Test\Test.txt',x'aabbccdd');
> UPDATE my_table_size SET counter=1 WHERE rowid=1;

The table `my_table_size` was automatically updated by a TRIGGER after the key-value pair was inserted to `my_table`. I then ran *sqldiff.exe* again, but this time with with `db2.sqlite` as first argument and `db1.sqlite` as second argument:

```
sqldiff db2.sqlite db1.sqlite
```

and got the following output:

> DELETE FROM my_table WHERE rowid=1;
> UPDATE my_table_size SET counter=0 WHERE rowid=1;

---

**sqldiff download links**

Since [SQLite version 3.10.2](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_10_2.html) which was released on January 20, 2016, binaries for *sqldiff* can be directly downloaded from the [SQLite Download Page](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html). They can be found in the *sqlite tools* archives for the corresponding operating systems (see the *Precompiled Binaries* sections). For example, here are the links to the 64-bit *sqlite tools* archives of version 3.45.1:

- [SQLite tools for Linux (x64)](https://sqlite.org/2024/sqlite-tools-linux-x64-3450100.zip)
- [SQLite tools for OS X (x64)](https://sqlite.org/2024/sqlite-tools-osx-x64-3450100.zip)
- [SQLite tools for Windows (x64)](https://sqlite.org/2024/sqlite-tools-win-x64-3450100.zip)

For SQLite versions prior to version 3.10.2, the SQLite website hosts 32-bit binaries for *sqldiff*, but does not link to them. Here are the links to *sqldiff* of version 3.8.10:

- [sqldiff for Linux (x86)](https://www.sqlite.org/2015/sqldiff-linux-x86-3081000.zip)
- [sqldiff for OS X (x86)](https://www.sqlite.org/2015/sqldiff-osx-x86-3081000.zip)
- [sqldiff for Windows (x86)](https://www.sqlite.org/2015/sqldiff-win32-x86-3081000.zip)

If you need other binaries, please refer to the [SQLite Download Page](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html). That page also offers the raw sources that you can compile yourself. (The file *sqldiff.c* is located in the *tool* sub-directory of the archive containing the sources.)

Comment: Does anyone have any info on the efficiency of sqldiff?

Comment: @malhal: I'm by no means a database expert, but I took a quick look at _sqldiff.c_. The tool opens the first database and attaches the second database to it. Then all tables are compared one by one. The comparison complexity seems to be linearly with the size of the databases. Regarding efficiency I can only guess, but since the tool is from the developers of SQLite themselves, it can't be _that_ bad...

Answer (score 57):

One possibility is to use the `sqlite3` command line client to export both databases and then diff the output. For example,

```
sqlite3 first.sqlite .dump >first.dump
sqlite3 second.sqlite .dump >second.dump
diff first.dump second.dump
```

Comment: It is sometimes difficult to guess what table the difference is in, but I will do without at first. An awk script might be able to show the table each diff comes from.

Comment: Or this (http://www.fmpromigrator.com/products/sqlite_diff/index.html). NOTE: This is a paid product, $25 at the time of this writing, and I'm NOT in any way related to the authors.

Comment: @laalto can you explain the 1st line, what is .dump and first.sqlite. I am newbie to sqlite. I have 1.db3 and 2.db3. I want to compare these two schema and data also, can I use this ?

Comment: @Jeshwanth Kumar N K: `.dump` is a command recognized by the `sqlite3` command line client. `first.sqlite` and `second.sqlite` are the names of sqlite database files you want to diff.

Comment: Oh thanks @laalto, I have tries the commands but getting an ERROR like this : **sqlite3: symbol lookup error: sqlite3: undefined symbol: sqlite3_enable_load_extension**

Comment: @JeshwanthKumarNK, A more straightforward way without piping is `sqlite3 file.db .dump>output.txt`. Or `sqlite3 -cmd .dump file.db>output.txt`

Comment: @laalto, Indeed, why did you pipe instead of simply doing `sqlite3 first.sqlite .dump >first.dump`?

Answer (score 12):

It's for Windows only, but there's a free/open source SQLite database comparison app on Code Project: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/220018/SQLite-Compare-Utility which works pretty well for me.

Comment: This didnt work for sqlite datadases pulled from android

Comment: How does this differ from the inbuilt default `sqldiff`?

Comment: sqldiff came out 2 years after my post

Answer (score 4):

Try [SQLite Diff](http://fmpromigrator.com/products/sqlite_diff/index.html).

NOTE: This is a paid product, $25 at the time of this writing, and I'm **not** in any way related to the authors.

Comment: How does this differ from the inbuilt default `sqldiff`?

Answer (score 2):

Since 20 January 2016 sqldiff (Windows sqldiff.exe) is included in the zip-file at http://sqlite.org/download.html

Comment: Linux http://sqlite.org/2016/sqlite-tools-linux-x86-3100200.zip OS X http://sqlite.org/2016/sqlite-tools-osx-x86-3100200.zip Windows http://sqlite.org/2016/sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3100200.zip

Comment: Note that the release.version.update,patch (rvvuupp is 3100200) may change soon (3.10.1 to 3.10.2 took only a week)

Answer (score 2):

There is a free web tool to compare SQLite databases, both schema and data - https://ksdbmerge.tools/for-sqlite-online. It works on wasm-compatible browsers, including Firefox and Chromium on Linux.

I am the author of that tool, it is an uno-platform port of my desktop tool for SQLite. Unlike few other online tools I could find - it does not upload your data to the server to generate data diff. However it uploads schema to handle the rest of logic.